# Sum of values in Nested Json Array objects via MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, mongodb-query, pymongo

Wanted to find the sum of Nested json array via mongodb query:

$group is asking for _id for grouping each obj in array, which is not working.

The documents is like this :

```
{
 point : "3",
 created_date : "2022-06-19",
 "name" : "grpA",
 "value_format" : [
 {
    "data" : {
        "A" : 10,
        "B" : 20,
        "C" : 30,
        "D" : 40,
     },
     "key" : "key1"
  },
     "data" : {
        "A" : 50,
        "B" : 60,
        "C" : 70,
        "D" : 80,
     },
     "key" : "key2"
  }
]
}


Expected output : 

{
  "key" : "anything",
  "val" : {
             "sumA": 60,
             "sumB": 80,
             "sumC": 100,
             "sumD": 120,
          }
}
```

Comment: the `A,B,C,D`  are part of your stable schema or they are data that can have any value?
If they are data, saving data on fields is bad idea in mongodb,we can assume that all members have those A,B,C,D  or some others can have A11,B10,Z20 etc? Also you want to sum those for 1 document in in all the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- assuming that A,B,C,D is part of your schema and not unknown data
- and assuming that you want the sum for each document you can do this

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62dff97078a49d8782851468)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"sumA": {"$sum": "$value_format.data.A"},
    "sumB": {"$sum": "$value_format.data.B"},
    "sumC": {"$sum": "$value_format.data.C"},
    "sumD": {"$sum": "$value_format.data.D"}}}])
```

Query2

- assuming dynamic fields (data on fields(unknown schema) => complicated and slow query)
- and want to sum all collection not just in 1 doc
- unwind the `value_format`
- make all pair documents A:10 to {"k" : A, "v" 10}
- we need this to group by "k" (this is the problem with dynamic keys)
- unwind data
- group by this k
- and then back again to have the `sumA : ...` `arrayToObject`
- group by nil, and collect all in 1 document

*most likely you need query2, the complexity comes from the data on schema, and this is kinda fast way, it could be worse

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62dffd0978a49d878285146a)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": "$value_format"},
 {"$project": {"data": {"$objectToArray": "$value_format.data"}}},
 {"$unwind": "$data"},
 {"$group": {"_id": "$data.k", "sum": {"$sum": "$data.v"}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": 
     {"$arrayToObject": 
       [[{"k": {"$concat": ["sum", "$_id"]}, "v": "$sum"}]]}}},
 {"$group": {"_id": null, "val": {"$mergeObjects": "$$ROOT"}}}])
```

Query3

- this sums with unknown fields(like query2) but finds the sums for each document
- uses one extra collection with 1 empty document `one_doc_collection=[{}]`
- this is like a trick, when we want to use stage operators to an array, and we dont want to unwind all documents (we use the lookup and unwind locally)
- query is similar to query 2, just do those inside the lookup
  its big because data on fields, both in the original data and in the output

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62e1025978a49d878285146c)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
   {"value_format": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$value_format",
        "in": {"$objectToArray": "$$this.data"}}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"value_format": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": "$value_format",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}},
 {"$lookup": 
   {"from": "one_doc_collection",
    "pipeline": 
     [{"$set": {"value_format": "$$value_format"}},
       {"$unwind": "$value_format"},
       {"$group": 
         {"_id": "$value_format.k", "sum": {"$sum": "$value_format.v"}}},
       {"$replaceRoot": 
         {"newRoot": 
           {"$arrayToObject": 
             [[{"k": {"$concat": ["sum", "$_id"]}, "v": "$sum"}]]}}}],
    "as": "sums",
    "let": {"value_format": "$value_format"}}},
 {"$project": 
   {"sums": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": "$sums",
        "initialValue": {},
        "in": {"$mergeObjects": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}}])
```

Comment: But in 2nd Query, it is giving single document output for all the documents present in a collection. How to separate that , one to one, like one o/p for one document.   May be , i can make a function out of this query and call this fun for each doc. But in this case we would require a loop, which is not good.

Comment: i added one more query, to sum those with unknown fileds, but per document not in all the collection